# Position Logo at specific location with Text wrapping around

Tags: positioning

I have to provide a stack of slices of paper (vouchers) with a company-logo on the top right on the odd page (of some vouchers, but not on all) and no one on the even page. The Text is generated an of variable length (so one voucher can span over three pages).
The problem I have no idea how to solve is, that I want the Text adjust to the Logo.

```
HEADER                        -LOGO-
text text text text text te-  -LOGO-
xt text text text text text   -LOGO-
text text text text text te-
xt text text text text text text te-
```

I tried with textpos for the positioning, but 1st the Text floats into the Logo and 2nd it will not be repeated on the second odd page.

Any Ideas for packages I should take a look into?

**EDITH:** package wrapfigure could do the trick, thanks.

Now I need a package, that automatically repeats the wrapfigure on every odd page (until deactivated)

**EDIT**

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=99mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % generates filler text
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\title{Package Example}
\author{writeLaTeX}
\includegraphics[width=40mm]{logo.png}
\lipsum[1-10]
\cleardoublepage
%=======================================================================
%From here on, there should be no more logos
\lipsum[1]
\cleardoublepage
%========================================================================
% maybe here could the logo-thingy start again
\end{document}
```

Vielen Dank,
Peter

Comment: For the text wrapping, this might help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118602/how-to-text-wrap-an-image-in-latex

Comment: If only the repetition is missing, why don't you post a small MWE for one page and we can try to help to repeat it on every odd page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to text-wrap an image in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118602/how-to-text-wrap-an-image-in-latex)