# Place a quote half over margin

Tags: environments, boxes, quoting

I would like to place quotes in my document like in the template below. Ideally it would be a new environment that could be used multiple times easily. The quote should be halfway over the margin, in a bigger bold font to highlight key facts from the text.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

[image: quote aside]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you already tried something by yourself? For a quick solution, you put your quote inside a `wrapfigure` environment, instead of a picture as shown in [how to text-wrap an image in latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132313/64454). For what regards the margin overlapping, you could play around with real/fictional boxes dimensions.

Comment: well, i came up with this: `\begin{figure}
\begin{quotation}
this is the quote
\end{quotation}
\end{figure}`
 but I don't know how to place the figure environment to the side and over the margin...

Comment: ok, thanks - wrapfig is not bad, but it doesn't overlap over the margin...

Comment: I've edited you title, so that your question focuses on your main issue only. (To use a bold typeface, just uses the `\textbf{<text>}` macro, and `\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}` (from the `xcolor` package) to change text color.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `wrapfigure` environment (from [`wrapfig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package). This environment creates a box making the main text wrap around it. You can specify the width of this box and its position (`l`eft, or `r`ight, as well as `i`nside, or `o`utside for double-sided documents). Moreover, this package natively include the specification of the overhanging width.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{<position: l, r, i, or o>}[<overhang width>]{<total width of the wrapfigure>}
    <content of the wraping figure>
\end{wrapfigure}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}[.1\textwidth]{.4\textwidth}%
            \textbf{\sffamily\Large\textcolor{blue!50!black}{``Good things might come to those who wait\dots''}}%
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Original answer

> *This solution uses a `parbox` inside the `wrapfigure`, instead of the native overhang option of `wrapfig`. It is thus bulkier than the one suggested above in the edit.*

This solution uses the `wrapfigure` environment (from [`wrapfig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package). This package defines a floating box that the text wraps around. You can specify the width of this box and its position (left or right):

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{<position: R or L>}{<width of the wrapfigure>}
    <content of the wraping figure>
\end{wrapfigure}
```

We fill this box with our quote. In order to make the text run across the margin, we put this text inside another box, a `parbox`, *having a wider width* than the one defined by the `wrapfigure` environment:

```
\parbox{<width of the box>}{<content of the box>}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{.2\textwidth}%
        \parbox{.4\textwidth}{%
            \textbf{\sffamily\Large\textcolor{blue!50!black}{``Good things might come to those who wait\dots''}}%
        }%
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

---

MWE with explicit boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}{.2\textwidth}%
        \fbox{\parbox{.3\textwidth}{\textbf{\Large Good things might come to those who wait\dots}}}%
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: great thanks! however, there is a problem if there are other graphics, the wrapfigure is behind it and not closed... like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0329olwdno10uyr/Screenshot%202017-02-02%2010.11.50.png?dl=0  if there is no graphic following, it works nicely...

Comment: @Mario I've edited my answer: the `wrapfigure` environment  has an optional argument than makes the use of a `parbox`  superfluous

Comment: great, now it really works nicely. just one last thing: now the quote is always at the top of a paragraph. is it possible to place in the middle of a long paragraph?

Comment: @Mario [`wrapfig` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) states on page 2: *"It is convenient to begin the environment between paragraphs, but if you want
placement in the middle of a paragraph, you must put the environment between
two words where there is a natural line break"*