# Place text next to image

Tags: graphics, text

I was following the [solution given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118602/how-to-text-wrap-an-image-in-latex) to try get this effect:
[image]

but this solution was unsuccessful.  This is what outputs from the code given below:

[image]

Can you help me get the text to show up next to the figures as in the first image above?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\authorimg}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-.3\baselineskip}{%
    \includegraphics[
      height=\baselineskip,
      width=\baselineskip,
      keepaspectratio,
    ]{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\authorimg{example-image-a}] FONTS\\The range of fonts on your\\
computer is often highly distinctive\\(unless you only have the fonts\\the machine came with)
\item[\authorimg{example-image-b}] SCREEN SIZE\\Though easily switched, this\\setting can be a useful aspect of\\your devices's fingerprint
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not consider using a tabular environment instead of an itemize env? Should the image really only have a height and width of `\baselineskip`? I would guess you want an image of the same height as the words on the right?

Comment: @Troy, thanks for your input.  I would ideally like the images the same height as the words to the right.  How can I make this happen?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: fonts]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{C{2.8cm}  L{5.5cm}}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} & FONTS \newline 
        The range of fonts on your computer is often highly distinctive (unless you only have the fonts the machine came with) \\
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} & SCREEN SIZE \newline 
        Though easily switched, this setting can be a useful aspect of your device's fingerprint \\
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} & SOFTWARE \newline 
        Do you have an art director's toolkit or are you an unrepentant gamer? Or both?
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I fixed the widths of both columns in order to reproduce something similar to what you have, solution referenced [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12712/117534). These allow for manual line breaking via `\newline`, which is what I used to line break from `FONTS` etc.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

with use of `miniage` in the first item only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\authorimg}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-.3\baselineskip}{%
    \includegraphics[
      height=\baselineskip,
      width=\baselineskip,
      keepaspectratio,
    ]{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\authorimg{example-image-a}] \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\baselineskip\relax}
                                    FONTS\\The range of fonts on your\\
                                    computer is often highly distinctive\\
                                    (unless you only have the fonts\\
                                    the machine came with)
                                    \end{minipage}
\item[\authorimg{example-image-b}] SCREEN SIZE\\Though easily switched, this\\setting can be a useful aspect of\\your devices's fingerprint
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Addendum: to have bigger image you need

- to define bigger `labelwidth` (that image has space in label)
- image size accommodate to label width

For example, that image size should be equal to `4\baselineskip` than yo can change above MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand*{\authorimg}[1]%
    { \raisebox{-1\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=\imagesize]{#1}}}
\newlength\imagesize    % new lwngth for determining image size and label width

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1.2\imagesize,labelwidth=\imagesize]% left margin is 20% bigger than label width
    \setlength\imagesize{4\baselineskip}
\item[\authorimg{example-image-a}] \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-1.2\imagesize\relax}
                                    FONTS\\
                                    The range of fonts on your\\
                                    computer is often highly distinctive\\
                                    (unless you only have the fonts\\
                                    the machine came with)
                                    \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution!  How do I change the size of the image though?

Comment: @Joe, see addendum to my answer.